# SQL-datatype for cell-values in a spreadsheet-like sql-structure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I'm creating something that could be looked on as a spreadsheet, though it has many differences.
Each column represents an object from an object-table.

Objects-Table:

- id: Primary Key int
- name: varchar

Each row represents an action from an action-table

Actions-Table:

- id: Primary Key int
- actionType: tinyint

There's a many-to-many linking table for these two which could be looked upon as cells. Each non-null cell has an entry in it.

ObjectsActions-Table

- objectId: Foreign Key int
- actionId: Foreign Key int
- value: ?

Each action has an actionType-property. With most types all the cells will contain integer-values. But with a few they will also contain strings.

Here's where my question comes in. I realize this might be hard to answer and many things play in. But maybe there's some big no-nos or general rules of thumb or something.
What should be the data-type of the value-property of the ObjectsActions-Table

**Option 1.**
Should they be of type varchar? When getting the cells-values of a row(action) with an actionType which expects integer-values then each string should be converted to an int.

**Option 2.** Would it be sensible to instead let the type be binary?(sqlce "binary" type)? I suppose I could make each integer take up much less space that way?

**Option 3.** Should I have two(or more) ObjectsActions-Tables? One for string and one for int? Then when joining the Actions-Table with the ObjectsActions-tables we first check the action-type and then join with the appropriate table?

Comment: You could use multiple fields in ObjectsActions table - one for int, one for nvarchar etc. Add there ValueType field also; for reading it helps to decide, which kind of value you'll need, for writing you should create some logic, which type of values to fill.

Comment: Thanks, but actionType in the Actions-Table basically tells the ValueType. Each cell in one row/action will all have the value-types so it seems redundant to specify it for each cell? And it feels wrong to have one field for varchar, one for int, etc for each cell/ObjectsActions when only a single one of them will ever be used at a time. Or is there something I'm not getting?

Comment: You can use only varchar one, but then you must adhere strict rules for value conversion and validation. We are using something similar to store various settings; every read must validate value against required type and convert when needed. Integers are simple; dates are much harder to keep consistent :) In short, Option 1 from your description.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really worrying about being able to do it. I'm more thinking of what would be best way for performance and diskspace. But maybe I'm worrying too much..